# React - get data from API and show in return using MAP function

Tags: reactjs, api, map-function

I got a JSON from API and i am trying to show this data in return function using MAP function.

But i am getting this.

TypeError: this.state.callHistory.map is not a function

Please help me with **total_calls** also.

getCallHistoryList function working fine because i got data in network tab of browser dock.

Mainfile.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Acallhistory extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        callHistory:[],
    };
  }   

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  componentDidMount(){
    this.getCallHistoryList();
  }

  getCallHistoryList() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("AuthToken");
    const filterToken = token.replace(/['"]+/g, '');
    const payload = {
      from_date:'2021-05-17',
      to_date:'2021-05-07'
    }

    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://APIURL',
      data: payload,
      headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       'Authorization': 'Bearer' + filterToken,
      }, 
    }).then((response) => {
        this.setState({ callHistory: response.data.data });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      });
  };

  render() {
      return (
        <div>

             **<h5>Total calls: {this.state.callHistory.average_detail.total_calls} </h5>**  
        
                 <table class="table table-responsive">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Interpreter</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                     {this.state.callHistory.map(member => 
                      <tr>
                        
                        <td>{member.call_datas.from_user_profile.first_name}</td>
                        
                      </tr>
                     )} 
                      
                    </tbody>
                 </table>
        </div>
      )    
  }
}

export default Acallhistory;
```

My JSON look like this-

```
{
    "status": true,
    "data": {
        "average_detail": {
            "total_calls": 6,
            "total_available_interpreter": 4,
            "avg_call_wait_time": "",
            "most_active_location": ""
        },
        "call_datas": [
            {
                "id": 6,
                "from_user_profile_id": 35,
                "from_user_role_id": 7,
                "purpose_id": 1,
                "language_id": 1,
                "action": 1,
                "status": {
                    "id": 10,
                    "name": "request",
                    "value": "Request"
                },
                "remarks": null,
                "is_recall": 0,
                "call_detail": "",
                "from_user_profile": {
                    "id": 35,
                    "user_id": 41,
                    "company_id": 2,
                    "first_name": "akshay",
                    "last_name": null,
                    "profile_photo": null,
                    "gender": null,
                    "date_of_join": null,
                    "date_of_birth": null,
                    "company": {
                        "id": 2,
                        "company_name": "AMAZON INDIA",
                        "company_type": 2,
                        "con_name": "ANKIT BOKARE",
                        "con_email": "ankitb.verve@gmail.com",
                        "company_address1": "Brigade Gateway, 8th floor, 26/1",
                        "company_address2": "Dr. Rajkumar Road, Malleshwaram(W)",
                        "company_city": "Bangalore",
                        "company_state": "Karnataka",
                        "company_country": "INDIA",
                        "company_zipcode": "560055",
                        "created_by": 1,
                        "updated_by": 1,
                        "deleted_at": null,
                        "created_at": "2021-04-21T05:16:49.000000Z",
                        "updated_at": "2021-04-21T05:16:49.000000Z"
                    },
                    "locations": {
                        "id": 34,
                        "user_profile_id": 35,
                        "city_id": 5,
                        "miles": "1",
                        "region": "1",
                        "site": "Gujrat",
                        "deleted_at": null,
                        "created_at": "2021-05-23T08:47:24.000000Z",
                        "updated_at": "2021-05-23T08:50:54.000000Z"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "from_user_profile_id": 35,
                "from_user_role_id": 7,
                "purpose_id": 1,
                "language_id": 2,
                "action": 1,
                "status": {
                    "id": 10,
                    "name": "request",
                    "value": "Request"
                },
                "remarks": null,
                "is_recall": 0,
                "call_detail": "",
                "from_user_profile": {
                    "id": 35,
                    "user_id": 41,
                    "company_id": 2,
                    "first_name": "akshay",
                    "last_name": null,
                    "profile_photo": null,
                    "gender": null,
                    "date_of_join": null,
                    "date_of_birth": null,
                    "company": {
                        "id": 2,
                        "company_name": "AMAZON INDIA",
                        "company_type": 2,
                        "con_name": "ANKIT BOKARE",
                        "con_email": "ankitb.verve@gmail.com",
                        "company_address1": "Brigade Gateway, 8th floor, 26/1",
                        "company_address2": "Dr. Rajkumar Road, Malleshwaram(W)",
                        "company_city": "Bangalore",
                        "company_state": "Karnataka",
                        "company_country": "INDIA",
                        "company_zipcode": "560055",
                        "created_by": 1,
                        "updated_by": 1,
                        "deleted_at": null,
                        "created_at": "2021-04-21T05:16:49.000000Z",
                        "updated_at": "2021-04-21T05:16:49.000000Z"
                    },
                    "locations": {
                        "id": 34,
                        "user_profile_id": 35,
                        "city_id": 5,
                        "miles": "1",
                        "region": "1",
                        "site": "Gujrat",
                        "deleted_at": null,
                        "created_at": "2021-05-23T08:47:24.000000Z",
                        "updated_at": "2021-05-23T08:50:54.000000Z"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "count": 6,
    "message": "translate.CALL_HISTORY_DATA",
    "totalNumberOfRecords": 6
}
```

Comment: Are you getting `callHistory` as an array?
if `callHistory` is an object, then you will get this error, as `map` is only a function of array and not an object

Answer (score 1):

`componentDidMount` gets called after the component has initially mounted.
Your initial state is an empty array so on 1st render this.state.callHistory will be an empty array. After mounting you will get the response from axios call and then store it into state.

Note: you seem to be assigning an object to the state which is an array

```
then((response) => {
        this.setState({ callHistory: response.data.data });
 })
```

I think this is what you want to do

```
then((response) => {
        this.setState({ callHistory: [response.data.data] });
 })
```

Just modify your render method to include a conditional check. Only render if this.state.callHistory has length greater than 0.

```
<div>

    {this.state.callHistory.length > 0 &&

             **<h5>Total calls: {this.state.callHistory.average_detail.total_calls} </h5>**  
        
                 <table class="table table-responsive">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Interpreter</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                     {this.state.callHistory.map(member => 
                      <tr>
                        
                        <td>{member.call_datas.from_user_profile.first_name}</td>
                        
                      </tr>
                     )} 
                      
                    </tbody>
                 </table>
      }
</div>
```

This will render only if the array contains response data. You may ofcourse modify the condition using ternary operator to have if else condition.